# Selenium 2- Is the Alert API supported by ChromeDriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Is the alert API supported in Selenium 2 for **Chrome**?  If not, is there a workaround, maybe using javascript injection?

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ChromeDriver was recently updated to add support for alerts as stated by the [blog here](http://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/). You can pick up the new ChromeDriver [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/downloads/list).

Comment: Thanks :)  You need to upgrade to the latest Chrome browser version too.